# Execute "sp_fulltext_service" in Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: sql-server, cloud

We got error when we use the default user "sqlserver":

> Msg 15247, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_fulltext_service, Line 13
> [Batch Start Line 0] User does not have permission to perform this
> action.

[microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-fulltext-service-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#permissions):

> Only members of the **serveradmin** fixed server role or the system administrator can execute **sp_fulltext_service**.

Comment: If you don't have/can't gain `sysadmin` priviledges, then no, you cannot use the procedure. It seems, however, what you are actually asking  is how to enable fulltext indexing in a Google hosted SQL Server instance, correct?

Comment: Hi,full text indexing  is working ., but we need to change fulltextserviceproperty('VerifySignature')  value  , thank you